# Is it safe to put env variables in the express server file

Tags: express, server, environment-variables

Is it wrong to put env variables in the express server file ? is it going to be seen by any one?

env variables in server file

Answer (score 0):

You should include it in gitignore file so no one gets the repo has access to env variables, also if you are using docker make sure to let it know about your env files when you deploy it as a service,
in case you are using cloud for hosting, include the env variables into the service configurations that way the info in the env file won't be exposed

Answer (score 0):

you should create an env file and put it in gitgnore so that in production you variables can not be exposed.This make  env file not to be exposed on version control like git, but you will have to define those env variables in your third party hosting service provider.

Comment: I do not want to put the app on github .. do I still need the gitignore file?

Comment: If you don't need to put on github I think there is a need to use it if it is a local app(In development).

Comment: @KayitareAudax No he doesn't need to use git. Git is for a group of programmers to track development progression of an application. Or for self insurance, if you work on a big complicated project you might want to reverse last changes if you get some bug in the app.

Comment: @Mises that's what I was saying.

Comment: @KayitareAudax Read carefully what you wrote, "think there is a need to use it..." You wrote he needs, but no he do not need it.

Comment: So what do I need to do to store these sensitive data such as database connection string, api key, etc?

Comment: thanks @Mises it was a typo I wanted to say that he does not need it